# Get data between td tag using PHP

Tags: php, html

This is My code.

```
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
       echo "<form action="test.php" method="post"><tr><td>".$rows[$i]['id']."</td><td>".$rows[$i]['book_name']."</td>
       <td>".$rows[$i]['author_name']."</td><td>".$rows[$i]['publisher']."</td>
       <td>".$rows[$i]['publication_year']."</td><td>".$rows[$i]['subject']."</td>
       <td><input type='submit' value='get book'></td></tr></form>";
    }
```

I need to take data between td if Get Book button is clicked. I Get rows data from database.
If I need data from textbox I use name. $_POST['name'].
Likewise how can I get data from td tag?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $rows[$i]['publication_year'] correct the array  forgot the ]

Comment: Where do you get the `$rows` data from?

Comment: I get $rows data from database @IbrahimAshShohail

Comment: echo "<td><form action='test.php' method='post'>"; make form inside the td and correct the quotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an input element and pass the data through it.

A proposed solution is this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  echo '<tr>'.
    '<td>'.$rows[$i]['id'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$rows[$i]['book_name'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$rows[$i]['author_name'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$rows[$i]['publisher'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$rows[$i]['publication_year'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$rows[$i]['subject'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.
      '<form action="test.php" method="post">'.
        '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$rows[$i]['id'].'">'.
        '<input type="submit" value="get book">'.
      '</form>'.
    '</td>'.
  '</tr>';
}
```

Then you can get the id in php from the request parameters. e.g.:

```
$_POST['id'];
```